# Create a UIView with a 0.5 height in a Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I am using a `Storyboard` and have added a `UIView` to my `UIViewController`. I would like this view to be a thin `0.5` height line, but for some reason, every time I type `0.5` in for height `XCode` will change that back to `1`.

[image]

[image]

You can easily programmatically create a `UIView` with a `0.5` height, why can I not do this inside of a `Storyboard`?

Comment: This is odd because, when I used to use IB and Storyboards, I was frequently irritated by the (seemingly) arbitrary assignment of *.5 values to constraints. Funny that Xcode will do them automatically but not allow you to do it manually. I know it's a hack from your desired answer, but what about creating an IBOutlet to the constraint and modifying its constant in code? Or, you can be like me and give up IB altogether! ;-)

Comment: You can't make a _view_ that's half a point high, but you can certainly make a view that _draws_ a line half a point high. So just do that.

Comment: @matt - Possible in IB?

Comment: You'll have to write a very simple custom UIView subclass. But you can certainly add an instance of that UIView subclass in IB, sure. You want something like the MyHorizLine class that I describe in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch10.html#_subclassing

Comment: You can have a look at my answer on
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006311/grouped-uitableview-remove-outer-separator-line/38620724#38620724