# How to remove UITableView section header separator

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard

I would like to remove (or make them clearColor) UITableView's section header separators. Setting `tableView.separatorStyle = .none` doesn't work. I've also tried solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006311/grouped-uitableview-remove-outer-separator-line), but none of them actually worked for me (maybe because the answers are pretty old). I still get this tiny separator below the section header.

I created the UITableView in Storyboard and add a UITableViewCell there. Then I set it as a header like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerTableViewCell")
        return cell
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if section == 1 {
            return 49
        }
        return 0
    }
```

Comment: why you add cell in viewForHeaderInSection ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't know why you are returning `UITableViewCell` in `viewForHeaderInSection` method so may be it is possible that is showing separator of that `UITableViewCell`. Try returning the `contentView` of cell instead of cell from `viewForHeaderInSection` method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerTableViewCell")
    return cell.contentView
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    return headerView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by following way:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.01
    }
```

Comment: Actually this is a great way. Although you can just do `return 0`.

Comment: Under some circumstances, 0 is ignored (Grouped View). You should return `CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out overriding `layoutSubviews` **removes all the cell's separators**, both section-related and cell-related.

```
@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell

@end    

@implementation MyCustomCell

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    // don't call [super layoutSubviews]
    // can be left empty
    // does not harm other UI elements inside the contentView
}

@end
```

In multiple-cell sections, you may just want to only remove the Section-related separators (at the top of first cell and at the bottom of last cell), keeping inset, inter-cell, separators shown:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        if ([view isEqual:self.contentView]) continue;

        view.hidden = view.bounds.size.width == self.bounds.size.width;
    }
}
```