# UITableViewCells bottom edge flickering when app enters foreground

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I've build an app which contains an UITableView with a bunch of cells. Inside the cells I've got a view, which fill the whole cell. I've configured the tableview like this:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 24/255.0, green: 34/255.0, blue: 41/255.0, alpha: 100)
tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red: 26/255.0, green: 34/255.0, blue: 40/255.0, alpha: 100)
```

Whenever the app enters the foreground, I got those little lines flickering for 0.5 seconds or so. To be clear, I don't want those.

[image]

And this is how it looks like when the app fully entered the foreground, and how it is supposed to look like:

[image]

Any ideas how to get rid of them?

EDIT 1:

I'm starting to doubt that the flickering is related to the separators, because it is only happening between cells in a section, not between the section-cell and the first cell in a section. I've grabbed some screenshots of the view hierarchy and the constraints related to the view (Foreground view) I show in the cell.

[image] 
[image]

EDIT 2:

If I set the top and bottom constraint to -2 instead of 0, there's no flickering at all, however it's not as I want it visually. So the flickering is not related to the separators at all.

Comment: Where are you setting the `tableView.separatorStyle = .none`? Is it in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Yea, it's in the viewDidLoad. I tried viewWillAppear too, without any luck.

Comment: Did u trying this in Simulator or Real Device ???

Comment: Real device only, haven't tried it on the simulator.

Comment: Are you using a launchScreen or launch Images? If you are not using a launch screen try switching to one see if that helps.

Comment: I am, but as mentioned it's just a problem when it enters foreground from background, not when the app initially is launched.

Comment: Are you using sections or simply just one section

Comment: If you build a minimal working example, which can be used to replicate the issue, it would be much easier to help.

Comment: @kathayatnk I'm using multiple sections.

Comment: Try adding `Renders with edge antialiasing.'  true  to your inf'o.plist

Comment: are you reloading the tableview or updating the data source when coming to foreground?

Comment: can you try setting a background color to the separator as the same color as tableview background? this way if the line doesnt appear when you come to foreground from background, we can confirm that the line separator is the issue.

Comment: Also can you try setting "Renders with edge antialiasing" to YES in your info.plist?

Comment: You aren't supposed to vote down if an answer doesn't work for you. Just imagine if people simply didn't like your question just for kicks and started voting down, how'd the situation be for you. Voting down should be done when the answer either is way off base, or is not presented clearly. Reps are prized possession, you should not eat into other people's for no good reason.

Comment: @Recusiwe - setting "Renders with edge antialiasing" worked?

Comment: Also i can see that someone downvoted me because i was at 2. Is it fare? Do any one know how to raise this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Trick for removing the cell separators.

Objective-C

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
}
```

Swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually flickering happens when you're returning a wrong heightForRowAtIndexPath.
In your case, you're returning a little smaller than your cell's actual height I guess.
So try to set "clipToBounds" of your cell to "true" and check if it works.

Comment: @Recusiwe one more strange thing that I noticed is that the ContentView of your TableViewCell is missing. By default, when you're dragging UITableViewCell to IB it comes with a ContentView. But in your screenshot, it's missing. Or you've just renamed it?

Comment: I just renamed it, it's the "Background Container View"

Answer (score 1):

Try setting "Renders with edge antialiasing" to YES in your info.plist.

Answer (score 1):

I think here your issue with `UITableViewStyle`. Right now you are using `UITableViewStyle` `Grouped`. So, line between cell isn't `UITableViewCellSeparator` it's Group Table 1 pixel header and footer space. So,

I have two solutions:

- Either use `UITableView` background color same as cell background color.
- Change `UITableView` style to `Plain`

**GroupTable SS**

[image]

or

**PlainTable SS**

[image]

I hope it'll help you. And solve your issue :)

Comment: Where do you see I use grouped? I use Plain actually.

Comment: Share your class file.. It'll better to crack

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not related to the separator, because the separator doesn't cover the whole screen, it must be related to your constraints, try changing the background color of the `BackgroundContainerView`, the `DepartureCell` and the `TableView`, one of these 3 views should have the dark grey color as a background color.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible that the tableview is inherited from another one and ***seperatorStyle*** could be set different in the super class? Then, you need override it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the tableview separator color with full transparency it might help

```
tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red: 26/255.0, green: 34/255.0, blue: 40/255.0, alpha: 0)
```

Do this in viewWillAppear

If that will not help check the view hierarchy maybe there is an issue with the cell rendering in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35805392/9497657) and its swift 4 update

or try adding this extension to your ViewController

```
extension UITableViewCell {
func removeCellSeparators() {
    for subview in subviews {
        if subview != contentView && subview.frame.width == frame.width {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
  }
}
```

then try calling it in just before you return the cell

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCellIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    cell.removeSeparators()

return cell
}
```

if this doesn't help then please post more information about your setup, code or maybe host a minimal version of your app with the tableView having the issue on gitHub so that I can help.

EDIT 1:

Try setting the rowHeight / cellHeight to 15 pixels more than what it currently is if that will solve your problem than the cellHeight is what needs tweaking could be that it only needs to be 2-4 pixels higher. Probably as the app is entering the foreground autolayout is trying to do what it can do show everything as you want however some constraints are ambiguous therefore whilst entering from the background there is the view appearing animation from the system for about half a second and there is your flickering as well.

Comment: Both solutions are not working. Plus the linked answer is only for section separators.

Comment: Are you using storyboards or creating the tableView in code?

Comment: I use storyboards, and I'm starting to think that the problems isn't related to separators, but my contraints.

Comment: Because the flickering only occurs in between cells in sections, not between the sections and the first cell.

Comment: Could you extract the tableView code into a separate project so I can replicate the issue and be able to help you or share the current project on github??

Comment: Try setting the rowHeight / cellHeight to 4 pixels more than what it currently is

Comment: But I want the rounded corners which this would ruin, right?

Comment: It shouldn't do. As the corner radius is left untouched. Try it and see if it resolves the flickering issue then we can go ahead and fix other issues if any will appear

Comment: Have you tried the solution?? Have you managed to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Set this in viewDidLoad()

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

Comment: Share your class

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as per follows, from your storyboard to avoid that separator from UITableView.

[image: Do it like this]

Answer (score 0):

If you set

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

on `viewDidLoad()`, it will flicker

you need to it before like in `viewWillAppear()` or in the storyboard

Comment: Heh, did you just vote me down? Share proper code and we could help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Xcode "Debug View Hierarchy" to find question View , and use "KVC" remove that view.
ps. my english is poor , i hope i can help you

Answer (score 0):

1. From storyboard select table view separator to None.
2. In Separator Inset select custom and remove left value make it from 15 to 0.
3. Build and run it again now check.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make `tableView`'s `backgroundColor` and `separatorColor` exactly the same as in:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 24/255.0, green: 34/255.0, blue: 41/255.0, alpha: 100)
tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red: 24/255.0, green: 34/255.0, blue: 41/255.0, alpha: 100)
```